# How to store Image with some data in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, image, spring-boot

For example:

I want to store Employee detail such as

```
private Long id;
private String Name;
private String country;
```

Now, I also want to store an Image along with above data in MongoDB.

In my Controller, I have written below code its a snippet

```
Employee employee2 = new Employee(); 
employee2.setEmpId(1002);
employee2.setEmpName("Dinesh Rajput");
employee2.setCountry("India");

mongoOperations.save(employee2);
```

Employee data is created in DB. Now how to store image along with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the code like the following

```
DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
metaData.put("mobileNo", mobileNo);
metaData.put("FileName", fileName);
metaData.put("createDate", new Date());
```

[it will be saved in db like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv7o0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot, Spring Data Mongo then you should consider using [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for Mongo for the content storage piece like this:

Add the following dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-mongo-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you have a GridFsTemplate bean present in your application context.  Something like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig

   @Bean
   public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
      return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
   }
   ...
```

To allow content to be associated with your Employee entity, give it the following attributes:

```
@ContentId
private String contentId;

@ContentLength 
private long contentLength = 0L;

@MimeType
private String mimeType = "text/plain";
```

Add a store interface:

```
@StoreRestResource(path="employeeImages")
public interface EmployeeImageStore extends ContentStore<Employee, String> {
}
```

That's all that you need.  When you application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Mongo/REST modules and it will inject an implementation of the `EmployeeImageStore` store for GridFs as well as an implementation of a controller that supports full CRUD functionality and maps those operations down onto the underlying store interface.  The REST endpoint will be available under `/employeeImages`.

i.e.

`curl -X PUT /employeeImages/{employeeId}` will create or update an employee's image

`curl -X GET /employeeImages/{employeeId}` will fetch the employee's image

`curl -X DELETE /employeeImages/{employeeId}` will delete the employee's image

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).

HTH

Comment: Can i use spring content with reactive mongo. If yes can you provide me link to an example

Comment: Sadly, we don't support any reactive stuff at the moment.  Happy to discuss use cases though.  What we offer today already streams the content through the application (much like a reactive repository might stream structured data).  How would a reactive store differ from what we offer today?  Please feel free to create an issue if you want to discuss further.

Comment: After further study about GridFsTemplate it is useful when uplaoded content size is > 16 MB , so i used bson.Binary to store user profile image. But just for learning purpose i have created a project on github (https://github.com/haiderali22/spring-content-user ) , can you please look into it i cant figure how to save an image to store. Between i cant figure out why it cant find content bean in test

Comment: Sure.  I can take a quick look.

Comment: The spring content mongo storage module uses mongo's GridFs to actual store the content so you need to instantiate a GridFsTemplate bean for it to use.  Now, how you do that with the embedded mongo library/reactive repository you are using is not immediately clear to me.  I'll keep digging but that's as far as I got so far.

Comment: Ah I see.  So there is a ReactiveGridFsTemplate with a similar API to GridFsTemplate, just adapted to use the reactivesreams API.  Similarly, we would need to provide a ReactiveContentStore with an implementation that knows how to use ReactiveGridFsTemplate instead of GridFsTemplate as a Mongo ContentStore does today.  If you are interested in this then please feel free to raise an issue, or even better submit a PR.  Happy to help you work through it that way.

Comment: i am new to reactive stuff but will give it a try when free.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to achieve this.

1. Save image into local system and add property in your java object let's say `imagePath`.
2. Store it as binary data by using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Tutorial on how use [GridFs](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-gridfs)

Comment: But with the GridFs How I will add my employee properties?

Comment: Note that we can save additional metadata along with the file by passing a DBObject to the store method. For our example, the DBObject might look something like this:
`DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
metaData.put("empId", "1002");